# javascript runtime error function is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, function, web, runtime

I get this

> 0x800a1391 - javascript runtime error function is undefined

When I try and click the save button.

Here is my code:

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js">
    function disableSaveBtns(){
        document.getElementbyId("save").prop("disabled", true);
        document.getElementbyId("saveClose").prop("disabled", true);
    }
</script>

<div class="submit-btn row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <span class="btn-group tlbEdit">
            <a href="#" id="save" class="btn btn-sm btn-default saveObject" onclick="disableSaveBtns()" title="save changes">Save</a>
            <a href="#" id="saveClose" class="btn btn-sm btn-default saveObject closeObject" title="save changes and close ">Save &amp; Close</a>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = Model.id })" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btnCancelEdit" title="Cancel Edit">Close</a>
        </span>
        <span class="btn-group tlbClose">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-default openAll">Expand All</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-default closeAll">Collapse All</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've checked the function declaration and I'm fairly certain that there are no syntax errors but I could be wrong. Could someone tell me why I'm getting the above error?

Comment: You need a *separate* script tag to load jQuery.

Comment: Judging from the `~/Scripts` path and `href="@Url.Action` call, I suspect you're using something other than plain JS. Is the error coming from the browser or the server-side?

Comment: _The script may be defined within the contents of the SCRIPT element or in an external file. If the src attribute is not set, user agents must interpret the contents of the element as the script. If the src has a URI value, user agents must ignore the element's contents and retrieve the script via the URI._ [[Ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script tags with a src attribute must be empty. You need to remove the `src` attribute from your script tag, and create a new `empty` script tag to load jquery

> If the "src" attribute is present, the  element must be empty.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp

Answer (score 1):

You need a new   to put your code in. That should fix your problem.

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
function disableSaveBtns(){
        document.getElementbyId("save").prop("disabled", true);
        document.getElementbyId("saveClose").prop("disabled", true);
    }
</script>
```